# Change "user-shortcut" in Texmaker

Tags: texmaker, keyboard

If I create a personal shortcut in Texmaker it has the shortcut <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F1..F10</kbd>.

*I want to create a shortcut with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>w</kbd> for example*. How can I do that?

Comment: I stopped using Texmaker a while ago, but If I remember correctly, this isn’t possible. In fact, the maintainer even turned down a feature request I made specifically about changing the shortcuts for user commands. I ended up switching to TeXstudio, which originally was based on Texmaker and allows you to assign shortcuts any way you please.

Comment: @doncherry: Are you sure that there isn't any possibility to change the shortcuts?

Comment: I’m quite sure that this used to be the case when I used Texmaker, but at the moment I don’t even have the current version installed, so I can’t be sure. Perhaps a current Texmaker user will come across this question, or even the maintainer.

Comment: @doncherry: How does it work in TeXStudio? I think of something like that: If I press CTRL + SHIFT + S then TeXStudio shall insert into the editor something like: "created by 'my name'"

Comment: You’d create a user macro with this text (which can also contain scripting elements), then go into the settings, shortcuts, and assign that macro just about any keyboard shortcut you want. It’s pretty straightforward.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is essentially a feature request.